# Do we call a regular tetrahedron "orthocentric"?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

This question may be rather trivial, but I don't understand if a regular tetrahedron is orthocentric.

In Wikipedia's ["Orthocentric tetrahedron" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron), it is said that:

> "[A]n orthocentric tetrahedron is a tetrahedron where all three pairs of opposite edges are perpendicular."

And then, in the same article it is said that:

> "In an orthocentric tetrahedron the four altitudes are concurrent."

In the case of a regular tetrahedron, the four altitudes are concurrent (and therefore it has a orthocenter), though three pairs of opposite edges are not perpendicular.

I don't know which of these two criteria is defining in terms of calling a tetrahedron orthocentric. From the article, it seems like a regular tetrahedron is not orthocentric, but it would sound strange to me since it is one of just two tetrahedrons with actual orthocenters.

Maybe I don't understand something - English is not my first language.

Comment: Either criterion works. If each pair of opposite edges is orthogonal, then the altitudes will be concurrent, and vice-versa. (It's not super-difficult to prove, but it's admittedly non-obvious.) If it's easier for you to see that a regular tetrahedron meets one of these criteria —take your pick— then you get the other for free. (And, yes: a regular tetrahedron is orthocentric.)

Comment: You state that "three pairs of opposite edges [of a regular tetrahedron] are not perpendicular", but they *are*. (And they must be, since as I wrote above, the criteria are interchangeable.) It's helpful here to notice that a regular tetrahedron's vertices are exactly *half* those of a cube, and its opposite edges form the diagonals of opposite faces of that cube. (Do a web search for "tetrahedron inscribed in cube".) Those diagonals should be fairly-clearly orthogonal, so that the regular tetrahedron does indeed satisfy the orthogonal-opposite-edges property.

Comment: Incidentally, there are *lots* of tetrahedra with orthocenters besides regular tetrahedra and, say, [trirectangular tetrahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trirectangular_tetrahedron).

Comment: Thank you very much - now I see that. Indeed, regular tetrahedron and trirectangular tetrahedron are probably the only "characteristic" tetrahedra with orthocenters. Do you know if regular tetrahedron is the only one with its center of mass in the orthocenter?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the regular tetrahedron *is* the only tetrahedron whose center of mass is its orthocenter.